# app install using adb is failing on Raspi

Tags: raspbian, android

Tried installing an apk using adb on Raspi. Getting following error

Performing Streamed Install
adb: failed to install latest.apk:

Tried the same apk on laptop and able to install apk

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you trying to load this into to a connected phone, or doing it for use in an emulator? If the latter, I'll admit I have not tried, but running the android emu on any model of Pi is bound to be a disaster anyway (presuming it's possible, which I would guess it actually isn't).

Comment: Tried to load this on a physical device via usb debugging